# How to set a minimum number of rows to return from an association with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Let's say I have the following `include` in a getter function in sequelize to get some data.  How can I exclude the 'videos' array from the result if there is no videos in that category or set a minimum amount of rows needed to return?  Right now the result prints out each category with their respective videos and an empty videos array if there are none but i want it to exlude that category entirely if theres no videos.  I tried setting the `required` property on the videos model include but that didn't work.  I couldn't find anything on this so if someone who knows how to do this could chip in I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

```
    include: [
          {
             model: models.category,
             include: models.video,
          }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your data model but I will try to create an example that you can hopefully adapt. To set a minimum results in your include, you just insert a `limit` and `where` clause, like this:

```
include: [
    {
      model: models.category,
      include: models.video,
      limit: 10,
      where: {
        // it's a simple subquery to select all category IDs
        // that have at least 10 videos associated
        id: {
          [Op.in]: Sequelize.literal(
            `(SELECT categoryId FROM videos GROUP BY categoryId HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10)`
          ),
        },
      },
    },
  ];
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I had to edit your answer to include some edits I had to make to the query to get it to run